# Is this proof of the completeness of $\mathcal L^p$ incomplete?

Tags: probability-theory, proof-explanation, banach-spaces

I'm reading the proof of

> Let $(X_{n})$ be a Cauchy sequence in $\mathcal{L}^{p}$ with $p \ge 1$. Then there exists a random variable $X_{\infty} \in \mathcal{L}^{p}$ such that $X_{n} \rightarrow X_{\infty}$ in $\mathcal{L}^{p}$.

Here is the first part of the proof:

---

We need to do two things: first, we need to identify a candidate $X_{\infty}$. Once we have constructed such an $X_{\infty}$, we need to show that $X_{n} \rightarrow X_{\infty}$ in $\mathcal{L}^{p}$.

Let $M(N) \nearrow \infty$ be a subsequence such that $\sup _{m, n \geq M(N)}\left\|X_{n}-X_{m}\right\|_{p} \leq 2^{-N}$ for all $N$. As $\|\cdot\|_{1} \leq\|\cdot\|_{p}$ (recall that we assume $\left.p \geq 1\right)$, this implies $\sup_{m, n \geq M(N)} \mathbb{E}\left(\left|X_{n}-X_{m}\right|\right) \leq$ $2^{-N}$, and in particular $\mathbb{E}\left(\left|X_{M(N+1)}-X_{M(N)}\right|\right) \leq 2^{-N}$. Hence
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|X_{M(n+1)}-X_{M(n)}\right|\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}\left(\left|X_{M(n+1)}-X_{M(n)}\right|\right)<\infty
$$
where we have used the monotone convergence theorem to exchange the summation and the expectation. But then the series $X_{M(n)}=X_{M(1)}+\sum_{k=2}^{n}\left(X_{M(k)}-X_{M(k-1)}\right)$ is **a.s. absolutely convergent**, so $X_{M(n)}$ converges a.s. to some random variable $X_{\infty}$.

---

*My understanding:* The author said that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left \|X_{M(n+1)}-X_{M(n)}\right \|_1<\infty$ implies $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(X_{M(n+1)}-X_{M(n)}\right)$ converges. However, this is a property of Banach space for which we want to prove $\mathcal L^p$ to be. Here the argument seems cyclical to me.

Could you clarify my confusion?

---

**Update:** I have represent here a detailed proof to deepen my understanding.

Let $\| \cdot \|_p$ be the $\mathcal L^p$ norm. There exists a strictly increasing sequence $\psi : k \to \mathbb N$ such that $$\forall m,n \ge \psi (k) : \| X_m-X_n \|_p \le 2^{-k}, \quad k \in \mathbb N.$$

In particular, $$\| X_{\psi (k+1)} - X_{\psi (k)} \|_p \le 2^{-k}, \quad k \in \mathbb N.$$

Let $Y_n := \sum_{k=0}^{n} | X_{\psi (k+1)} - X_{\psi (k)} |$ for all $n$. Then $(Y_n)$ is a non-decreasing sequence of non-negative random variable. Let $Y:= \lim Y_n$ be the pointwise limit of $(Y_n)$. We have

$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbb E (Y) &= \mathbb E \left ( \lim Y_n \right ) \\
&= \lim \mathbb E \left (  Y_n \right ) \quad \text{by monotone convergence theorem} \\
&= \lim_n \sum_{k=0}^{n} \mathbb E( | X_{\psi (k+1)} - X_{\psi (k)} |) \\
&= \lim_n \sum_{k=0}^{n} \| X_{\psi (k+1)} - X_{\psi (k)} \|_1 \\
&\le \lim_n \sum_{k=0}^{n} \| X_{\psi (k+1)} - X_{\psi (k)} \|_p \\
&\le \lim_n \sum_{k=0}^{n} 2^{-k} < \infty.
\end{aligned}$$

It follows that $Y =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} | X_{\psi (k+1)} - X_{\psi (k)} | < \infty$ a.s. Hence $$X_\infty := \lim_{k} X_{\psi(k)} = X_{\psi (0)}+Y$$ converges a.s. Let's show that $\| X_n -  X_\infty\|_p \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Consider $Z_{n,k} = |X_n - X_{\psi(k)}|^p$ for all $n,k \in \mathbb N$. We have $\mathbb E ( Z_{n,k} ) = \|X_n-X_{\psi(k)}\|^p_p \le 2^{-pm}$ for all $n \ge \psi(m)$ and $k\ge m$. So $$\lim_k \mathbb E ( Z_{n,k} ) \le 2^{-pm}, \quad n \ge \psi(m).$$

Notice that $(Z_{n, k})_k$ is a sequence of non-negative random variables. By Fatou's lemma, $$\mathbb E (|X_n - X_\infty|^p) = \mathbb E \left ( \liminf_{k} Z_{n,k} \right ) \le \liminf_{k} \mathbb E ( Z_{n,k} ) \le \lim_k \mathbb E ( Z_{n,k} ) \le 2^{-p \psi^{-1}(n)}.$$

This means $\mathbb E (|X_n - X_\infty|^p) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. This completes the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Y$ is a non-negative (extended real valued) measuarable function with $EY <\infty$ then $Y <\infty$ with probability $1$.  Apply this to $Y= \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}|X_{M(n+1)}-X_{M(n)}|$

Comment: But how do we deduce that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(X_{M(n+1)}-X_{M(n)}\right) < \infty$ as the author said?

Comment: If $\sum |a_n|<\infty$ then $\sum a_n$ is convergent. This has nothing to do with Probability  theory. @Akira

Comment: Thank youu. I got it <3